# Date-time conversion in R

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I have created a file something like this:

```
> filesInside
         Date         Time
1  01:09:2013 10:35:49.997 
2  01:09:2013 10:35:50.197
```

How could I possibly make a function using

```
as.POSIXct()
```

and I should be get something like this:

```
> as.POSIXct("2013-09-01 10:35:50")
[1] "2013-09-01 10:35:50 NZST"
```

How can I make it as a function?

**My code so far:**

```
DateTime <- as.POSIXct(paste(filesInside$Date, filesInside$Time), format="%Y%m%d %H%M%S")
```

Appreciate a bit of help please. Cheers

Comment: A small reproducible example, the expected output, and what you have tried - very nice first question! +1!

Comment: Where does the NZST come from? Should it always be NZST?

Comment: I think this shows the local time. try the code yourself by typing `as.POSIXct("2013-09-01 10:35:50")` in R and see what code you get. Do you get something different?

Answer (score 3):

You may try this. The order of date-time components and separators in `format` should reflect those in the object to be converted. See also `?strptime`.

```
with(filesInside,
     as.POSIXct(paste(Date, Time),
                format = "%d:%m:%Y %H:%M:%S",
                tz = "NZ"))
# [1] "2013-09-01 10:35:49 NZST" "2013-09-01 10:35:50 NZST"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(lubridate)
dmy_hms(apply(filesInside, 1, paste, collapse=" "), tz="NZ")
# [1] "2013-09-01 10:35:49 NZST" "2013-09-01 10:35:50 NZST"
```

---

`lubridate` here is a cinch, especially with its collection of `dmy_hms`, `ymd` etc functions.

To properly paste across rows, simply use `apply(<data.frame>, 1, paste, collapse=" ")`